# How to Use SynonymMap In CustomAnalayzer of Lucene 6.2.0

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

I do not want to write my own Analyzer class. i have seen a new feature given by apache lucene CustomAnalyzer where you can Build your own Custom Analyzer .

```
Analyzer ana = CustomAnalyzer.builder(Paths.get(index))
.withTokenizer(StandardTokenizerFactory.class).addTokenFilter(LowerCaseFilterFactory.class)
.addTokenFilter(StandardFilterFactory.class).build();
```

so here i want to add one more option for addTokenFilter(SynonymFilter.class) where i will pass the default value to the analyzer like synonymMap,tokenstream and everything so i just want to Ask ..

```
addTokenFilter(StopFilterFactory.class, "ignoreCase", "false", "words", "stopwords.txt", "format", "wordset")
```

i have seen this example is possible to use in the same way like here StopFilter is defined 
Is it Possible to use SynonymMap inside custom analyzer or not ..and if Yes then how to do so ..
constructor for synonym filter is as such..

```
HashMap<String, String> synonymMap = new HashMap<String, String>(10);
    synonymMap.put("synonyms", "Facebook");
```

i am doing it like this

```
 SynonymMap.Builder builder = new SynonymMap.Builder(true);
    builder.add(new CharsRef("Facebook"), new CharsRef("YearBook,FaceB00k"), true);
    builder.add(new CharsRef("Facebook1"), new CharsRef("Fraud"), false);
    builder.add(new CharsRef("Suzie"), new CharsRef("Susan"), false);
    SynonymMap map = null;
    try {
        map = builder.build();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Analyzer ana = CustomAnalyzer.builder(Paths.get(index))
            .withTokenizer(StandardTokenizerFactory.class)
            .addTokenFilter(StandardFilterFactory.class)
            .addTokenFilter(LowerCaseFilterFactory.class)
            .addTokenFilter(SynonymFilterFactory.class,synonymMap)
            .build();
```

its giving me error like this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Resource not found: Facebook
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.ClasspathResourceLoader.openResource(ClasspathResourceLoader.java:67)
```

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path passed in to `builder` is not the index directory, but where it should look for configuration resources for this analyzer. The second argument of `addTokenFilter` is list of parameters, not a synonym mapping.

What you will want to do, is put your list of synonyms into a file in the directory mentioned above, and pass in that file name as the "synonym" parameter in your addTokenFilter call (as well as any other parameters you may need).